# Dual Boot Win 8 fail to boot Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

I have a new Pavilion dm1 with pre-installed Win 8, and i want to install Ubuntu 12 as a dual boot option.  I need a larger partition for Ubuntu than WUBI will allow.

I have downloaded 12.10 and installed onto a USB drive.
I changed bios on the laptop to allow booting from USB
I enabled legacy boot
I resized the partitions using the auto tool

I was able to go through the entire installation process.  When I rebooted the machine, there was no GRUB screen nor any option to choose Ubuntu.  Machine booted to Win 8.

I tried to reinstall.  Installation software did see Ubuntu and gave me the option to erase Ubuntu and reinstall- which I chose.  Same issue.

There seems to be a lot of conflicting information on how to set up Ubuntu on Win8.

thanks for any help getting this up.

Comment: Have you installed Grub or other program to make it possible dual-boot?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer, I finnaly was able to do it:

http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=es&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=es-419&ie=UTF-8&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Ftecnoubuntu.wordpress.com%2F2012%2F12%2F09%2Finstalar-ubuntu-12-10-junto-a-windows-8%2F&act=url

It's my blog